# aggregate group distinct on array of objects after querying

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have array of products where a product looks like this:

```
{
"invNumber":445,
"attributes": [
    {
        "id": "GR1",
        "value": "4",
        "description": "Re/Rek"
    },
    {
        "id": "WEBAKKUNDE",
        "value": "2",
        "description": "NO"
    },
    {
        "id": "WEBAKKUNDK",
        "value": "1",
        "description": "YES"
    },
    {
        "id": "WEBAKMONTO",
        "value": "2",
        "description": "NO"
    }
    {
        "id": "WEBPAKFTTH",
        "value": "2",
        "description": "NO"
    }
]
}
```

What i want to to is get all products that have `{"id":"WEBAKKUNDE",value:1}` or `{"id":"WEBPAKFTTH","value":"1"}` and from these products than only return  all distinct 
`{"id": "GR1"}` objects.

I am trying to to something like this:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$attributes'},
    {$match:{$or:[{$and:[{"attributes.id":"WEBAKKUNDE"},
    {"attributes.value":"1"}]},{$and:[{"attributes.id":"WEBPAKFTTH"},
    {"attributes.value":"1"}]}]}},
])
```

but i dont know how to get the distinct objects from the returned products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query.

[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to check if the array has input criteria followed by [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to project the GR1 element.

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on GR1 element to output distinct value.

Note - You will need to add GR1 criteria to the $match if you expect to have attributes without GR1 element for matching attributes.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
    "attributes":{
      "$elemMatch":{
        "$or":[
          {"id":"WEBAKKUNDE","value":"1"},
          {"id":"WEBPAKFTTH","value":"1"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "$arrayElemAt":[
        {"$filter":{"input":"$attributes","cond":{"$eq":["$$this.id","GR1"]}}},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I also needed to add `"as":"this"` to $filter , but it`s working :) thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match:{ "attributes.id" : "WEBAKKUNDE", "attributes.value":"1" } },
    { $unwind: "$attributes" },
    { $match: { "attributes.id": "GR1" } },
])
```

But lets explain it:

`$match:{ "attributes.id" : "WEBAKKUNDE", "attributes.value":"1" }` will find all documents that match the `id` and `value` attributes on the documents:

`$unwind: "$attributes"` will give us a document for array item, so in your example we end up with 5 documents.

`$match: { "attributes.id": "GR1" }` will filter out the remainding for the `id` being `GR1`

More reading:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind

Comment: Your $match returns all my products, so there is something wrong with it

Comment: Can you show an example output of what you expect after the query has run?

Comment: `{
        "id": "GR1",
        "value": "4",
        "description": "Re/Rek"
     }`,
       `{
        "id": "GR1",
        "value": "2",
        "description": "Network"
     }`,
     `{
        "id": "GR1",
        "value": "3",
        "description": "Passive"
     }`

Comment: That doesn't seem to match anything in your input?

Comment: in my input i have example of just one product, and if you see the attributes array has an object `{ "id": "GR1", "value": "4", "description": "Re/Rek" }`
 so other product have different value and desciption on this object, and i want to get the distinct objects  , but only on products that also have
 `{ "attributes.id" : "WEBAKKUNDE", "attributes.value":"1" }`